# error TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, zod

I'm trying to get the value of an checkbox. but when I run the build gives this error, actually I don't know if the error is on the schema or in the actually code.

src/routes/dashboard/registrar.tsx

```
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react"; 
 import { RegisterTicketSchema } from "@/lib/validationSchema"; 
 import { z, ZodError } from "zod"; 
 import { formatError } from "@/lib/utils"; 
 import InputErrorMessage from "@/components/InputErrorMessage"; 
 import Alert from "@/components/Alert"; 
 import { useAuth, useSupabaseClient } from "@/lib/AuthProvider"; 
  
 type FormData = z.infer<typeof RegisterTicketSchema>; 
  
 export default function RegistrarIngresso() { 
   const supabase = useSupabaseClient(); 
   const { user } = useAuth(); 
   const [errors, setErrors] = useState<FormData>(); 
   const [message, setMessage] = useState(""); 
   const [formSuccess, setFormSuccess] = useState(false); 
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>({ 
     name: "", 
     identifier: "", 
     combo: false, 
   }); 
  
   const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
  
     setFormSuccess(false); 
     setErrors(undefined); 
     setMessage(""); 
  
     const name = formData.name; 
     const identifier = formData.identifier; 
     const combo = formData.combo; 
  
     try { 
       RegisterTicketSchema.parse({ name, identifier, combo }); 
     } catch (err) { 
       if (err instanceof ZodError) { 
         const errs = formatError(err) as unknown as FormData; 
         setErrors(errs); 
         return; 
       } 
     } 
  
     const {data,error} = await supabase 
     .from("ingressos") 
     .insert([ 
         { 
             name: name, 
             identifier: identifier, 
             pdv: user?.email, 
             combo: combo 
         } 
     ]) 
     .select(); 
  
      if (error) { 
        setMessage(error.message); 
        return; 
     }else{ 
         let { name, identifier, combo } = data?.[0]; 
         let code = data?.[0].code.slice(0, 8); 
         setMessage("Ingresso registrado com sucesso!"); 
     } 
  
     // reset form 
     setFormData({ name: "", identifier: "", combo: false }); 
     setFormSuccess(true); 
     setMessage("Your name was updated successfully."); 
   }; 
  
   return ( 
     <> 
       <div className="w-11/12 p-12 px-6 py-10 rounded-lg sm:w-8/12 md:w-6/12 lg:w-5/12 2xl:w-3/12 sm:px-10 sm:py-6"> 
         {message ? ( 
           <Alert 
             className={`${formSuccess ? "alert-info" : "alert-error"} mb-10`} 
           > 
             {message} 
           </Alert> 
         ) : null} 
         <h2 className="font-semibold text-4xl mb-4">Registrar Ingressos</h2> 
         <p className="font-medium mb-4"> 
           Olá <b>{user?.email}</b>, Insira as informações do ingresso abaixo e a confirme. 
         </p> 
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="formRegister"> 
           <div className="form-control"> 
             <label htmlFor="name" className="label"> 
               Nome 
             </label> 
             <input 
               id="name" 
               name="name" 
               type="text" 
               value={formData?.name ?? ""} 
               onChange={(ev) => 
                 setFormData({ ...formData, name: ev.target.value }) 
               } 
               className="input input-bordered" 
             /> 
           </div> 
           {errors?.name ? ( 
             <InputErrorMessage>{errors?.name}</InputErrorMessage> 
           ) : null} 
           <div className="form-control"> 
             <label htmlFor="identifier" className="label"> 
               Identificador 
             </label> 
             <input 
               id="identifier" 
               name="identifier" 
               type="name" 
               value={formData.identifier ?? ""} 
               onChange={(ev) => 
                 setFormData({ ...formData, identifier: ev.target.value }) 
               } 
               className="input input-bordered" 
             /> 
           </div> 
           <div className="form-control"> 
             <label htmlFor="combo" className="label"> 
               Combo 
             </label> 
             <input 
               id="combo" 
               name="combo" 
               type="checkbox" 
               value={formData.combo ?? false} 
               onChange={(ev) => 
                 setFormData({ ...formData, combo: ev.target.value }) 
               } 
               className="checkbox" 
             /> 
           </div> 
           {errors?.identifier ? ( 
             <InputErrorMessage>{errors?.identifier}</InputErrorMessage> 
           ) : null} 
           <div className="form-control mt-6"> 
             <button type="submit" form="formRegister" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary"> 
               Registrar Ingresso 
             </button> 
           </div> 
         </form> 
       </div> 
     </> 
   ); 
 }
```

src/lib/validationSchema.ts

```
import { z } from 'zod'; 
 import { email, required, combo } from './validationRules'; 
  
 export const AuthUserSchema = z.object({ 
         email: email() 
 }); 
  
 export const AuthUserWithTokenSchema = z.object({ 
         email: email(), 
         token: required("Token"), 
 }); 
  
 export const RegisterTicketSchema = z 
         .object({ 
                 name: required('Nome'), 
                 identifier: required('Identificador'), 
                 combo: combo('Combo'), 
         });
```

src/lib/validation rules.ts

```
import { z } from 'zod'; 
  
 export const required = (name: string) => z.string().min(1, `${name} é obrigatorio`); 
 export const identifier = (name: string) => z.number().min(6, `${name} deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres`); 
 export const combo = (name: string) => z.boolean(); 
 export const email = (name = 'Email') => required(name).email(`${name} is not valid`); 
 export const password = (number = 5, name = 'Password') => 
         required(name).min(number, `${name} must be at least ${number} characters`);
```

I tried changing the Form data value to null and undefined to maybe debug it, but no success at all!

Comment: Are you able to update your question to indicate on what line you hit your TS error?